# Multiple subrepos in one github repo

Tags: git

I'm using bower, and I want to make a lot of custom components.

Bower it's just a package manager, give it a list of git uris and it will clone them in your "components" folder, now this is awesome, what I want to do is give it a list of 4 or 5 repos, those will be all custom packages I created, but I don't want to make 4 or 5 different repos on github, one for each component, can I make one repo and somehow add 4 or 5 sub-repos on it?

I can't use branches, because clone always clones the master branch, it seems. (I'm not very good with git so bear with me please).

Comment: Search for "git submodule" on google and you will find your answer.

Comment: `git clone` will clone all branches. But if these "components" are independent enough to warrant being in their own repos, why not create different repos for them. On the other hand, if they're not, why not put each into a subdirectory of a single repo?

Answer (score 0):

If that package manager wants the "components" to be repos, I guess you have to make different repos.

You could make a new Github account especially for this project and set all the needed repos over there, to keep your account clean.

I think you can hack this by using git tags: set each of your components on a different tag in the history of your one git repo and use them as "versions of the same repo".
Something like:

```
  add comp-1 to your repo
git-tag 1: comp-1
  remove comp-1 from the repo
  add comp-2 to the repo
git-tag 2: comp2
```

I would definitely not do that, though.